# Using React Native 0.69.9 which was ejected from expo when upgrading from RN 0.65. I want to upgrade the app to 0.72.5 or later versions

Tags: android, ios, react-native, xcode15

I even tried Upgrade helper. But, my app still using some libraries of expo and made some custom changes in android folder long back which I even can't recollect.

Main reason why I want to upgrade is, IOS AppStore giving below warning. Till now am using Xcode 14.3 without issues.
**"**Although delivery was successful, you may want to correct the following issues in your next delivery. Once you've corrected the issues, upload a new binary to App Store Connect.
ITMS-90725: SDK version issue - This app was built with the iOS 16.4 SDK. Starting April 29, 2024, all iOS and iPadOS apps must be built with the iOS 17 SDK or later, included in Xcode 15 or later, in order to be uploaded to App Store Connect or submitted for distribution.**"**.
So, need some help as I did not get ample information from google.

Here is my `Package.json` file

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.2",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.10.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-plugin-inline-dotenv": "^1.6.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "expo": "^46.0.20",
    "expo-auth-session": "~3.7.1",
    "expo-cli": "^5.4.4",
    "expo-constants": "~13.2.4",
    "expo-file-system": "~14.1.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~13.3.1",
    "expo-media-library": "~14.2.0",
    "expo-random": "~12.3.0",
    "expo-sharing": "~10.3.0",
    "expo-web-browser": "~11.0.0",
    "html-entities": "^2.3.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.9",
    "react-native-autocomplete-input": "^5.0.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.1.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.5.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.10.0",
    "react-native-input-spinner": "^1.7.12",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^9.1.0",
    "react-native-pager-view": "5.4.24",
    "react-native-pkce-challenge": "^5.1.1",
    "react-native-radio-buttons-group": "^2.2.10",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.9.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-webview": "11.23.0",
    "react-navigation-header-buttons": "^6.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rn-pdf-reader-js": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "./src/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}": [
      "npm prettier --write",
      "eslint src/*.js --fix-dry-run"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.6",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.30.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.24.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.11.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.1",
    "lint-staged": "^11.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  },
  "private": true,
  "name": "rpa-mobileapprovals",
  "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear which upgrade helper you tried, Expo's or React Native. Luckily Expo has a pretty simple way to [upgrade your Expo app](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/). You shouldn't have to touch React Native Upgrade Helper.

- Update to whichever expo sdk you prefer `npm install expo@latest` or `npm install expo@49` (SDK 49 is RN 0.72.4)
- Then upgrade all dependencies to match the upgraded SDK version `npx expo install --fix`.
- You need to make sure you read the [SDK changelogs](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough#sdk-changelogs) for the SDK version you are upgrading to. They contain important information about breaking changes, deprecations, and other changes that may affect your app.

If the Expo upgrade was not beneficial for you, the simplest option you have is to create a new expo app using the latest SDK, manually installing all of your dependencies, following each package's instructions to ensure correct installation, and copying your code over to the new app codebase. I've done this before, it's not as bad as it sounds. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks David for the response. I'm using bare work flow. Not expo any more. As I said ejected from expo long back. I tried react native upgrade helper.